# Can't tap last cell in UITableView (only in simulator 4")

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I'm having a strange problem when testing my app in the simulator. Everything works fine when I test on my iPhone 4S, and also when I simulate on the 3.5" simulator. However, when I run the 4" simulator I'm unable to select the last row in a UITableView.

I present the UITableView on the screen when I tap a button. When I tap the last cell in the tableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not called. Even weirder, if there is a button on the view (under the tableView), it will respond to the tap on the tableView cell. This is happening on both tableViews in my app in different ViewControllers.

Is there any reason why this would happen on the iPhone 5 and not the iPhone 4?

If there is any relevant code that could help please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that this isn't code related at all. You could have a view that is on top of your table preventing the taps.

There are 2 tricks you can do to find this. First, you can color all your views different bright colors and make them partially transparent. This lets you see through your views.

Or you can just try revealapp.com. I don't have any relationship to them except as a satisfied customer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll take a look at revealapp.

I don't think this issue is being caused by a view that's on top of the tableView, because I can still tap on a button that is below this particular cell (on the main view). So it's almost as if this particular cell isn't even there, if that makes any sense.

Comment: ahh yes, gotcha. Good luck with it!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?  I'm experiencing a similar problem.  My table view works fine for a 3.5" phone, but on a 4" phone (even a real 4S), the last row is not selectable.

Comment: did you try revealapp.com?